# Difference between point of sale like shopify and ecommerce solution like magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, e-commerce, shopify

I'm migrating to an ecommerce platform that would help me sell my products online to a wider user base. I am told Shopify/Zepo is an online shop for small businesses and Magento/woocommerce are solutions. What exactly is the difference between a "shop" and "solution"? Or what if I build a site from scratch? Where do I start from?

Comment: Before choosing any of the ecommerce platform you should consider some points like 1)opensource/paid platform (2) How many product do you have in you catalog? (3) Future scalability (4)support for that platform? Will you be having a in house support team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify/Zepo are SaaS ecommerce platforms which can handle milions of visits/transactions per day if your store is a real success.
Magento/woocommerce are 'own hosted' tools/platforms.
Both are ok to start with, but if you think you'll do good, be careful on the last ones. They might seem cheap at the beginning but they can eventually ruin your business.
When starting it's always wiser to start with a SaaS tool which has no upfront costs and allow you to download all your data (products, customers, orders) in case you want to move to another platform.
Starting with Magento or WooCommerce will force you to have a sys team or a web developer almost permanently doing server-packages updates and so, let alone security, performance and scalability issues.

Comment: Thank you.Shopify charges  $179.Do you think building an ecommerce site from scratch be cheaper ? Would I need an in house I.T. team then ?

Comment: @alexandresaiz - are you saying you'll never need a web developer if you go down the Shopify route?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe using an off-the-shelf SAAS **alone** will ever be enough for a successful ecommerce website.

If you want to have a successful ecommerce solution you will need at least a good web developer to keep your site up-to-date.

Moreover, there will be many opportunities such as integration with your back-end systems that an off-the-shelf SAAS might not be able to handle.

My advice is to find a good technical resource, even if it's just one web developer, and build your product together - invariably it's more about people than technology or platform.